# Incorrect text on screen

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hi I'm new to this unity and I'm making a 2d game the problem.I'm facing is displaying the right text in the screen , e.g I have a `score` count for keeping track of score and then I'm displaying this text through `count.text` , HOWEVER the problem is that when the game starts the text on screen displays "0", `score` is 0 as well, then I shoot an apple and the `score` becomes 1 as well as the `count.text` also becomes 1 however the text is still 0 on the screen, when I shoot another arrow the `score` and `count.text` shows value of 2 however on the screen it shows 1 and so on. I followed unity tutorial of roll the ball. here is my code

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class arrowcounttutorial : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject Arrow;
    public GameObject apple;
    public int score = 0;
    public Text count;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        this.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().AddForce (transform.right*1500.0f);
        //score = 0;
        //showcounttext ();
        count.text =  score.ToString ();
    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        Vector3 diff = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - transform.position;
        diff.Normalize();

        float rot_z = Mathf.Atan2(diff.y, diff.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, rot_z - 0);

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp (0)) {


            GameObject bullet_new;

            bullet_new = Instantiate (Arrow,new Vector2 (-0.23f, -3.78f), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
            RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition),Vector2.zero);
            if (hit.collider!= null ) {

                LeanTween.move(bullet_new,  hit.collider.transform.localPosition, 1);
                if(hit.collider.tag == "fruit")
                {           
                    score++;
                    //showcounttext();
                    count.text =  score.ToString ();
                    print(count.text);
                    Destroy(hit.collider.gameObject,1);
                    Destroy(bullet_new,1);


                }

            }


        }
    }
/*
    void showcounttext(){

        count.text =  score.ToString ();
    }
    */
}
```

Also if I initialize the score in void start the text remains 0 through out the level even if the score and count.text are 1,2,3,4,5 so on. What can I do?

**UPDATE**
I don't know how it worked but I called an invoke function `Invoke ("showcounttext",1);` and it worked. I won't delete the question in case someone else have this same problem :)

Comment: Any errors in console after you make a shoot?

Comment: No there are no errors

Comment: What version of Unity3D are you using? If older one, try `Canvas.ForceUpdateCanvases ();` just after `count.text =  score.ToString ();`

Comment: I don't see why your code doesn't work but I am assuming you haven't connected up `count` to a text field in the UI canvas.  When I do this I create a UIController that holds the canvas and contains references to the UI elements in the canvas.  I then add methods on the UIController to change things and it deals with the nitty gritty.  I think it's strange to have a reference to a UI element from a normal gameobject.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys it worked, please see my update

Comment: @trojanfoe it cant be true, as if the author didnt assign the Text component from inspector it would throw exception.

Comment: @JerrySwitalski That's a good point.

Comment: hi @melissa the way you solve problems like this is by adding many `Debug.Log` statements to your code. You'll soon discover what is and isn't happening.

Comment: @JoeBlow thanks joe I will keep this in mind :)

Comment: it's possible "LeanTween" is doing something weird.  comment that line out and try it.  let us know.

Comment: just For the record.  you see how you had to "Invoke" it.  when that happesn it usually means you have to wait until the next frame (no need to wait a whole second).  what i mean is THERE IS SOME PROBLEM, and you have to wait one frame (EVEN THOUGH YOU SHOULD NOT, OF COURSE, HAVE TO DO THAT).  in that case what you do is simply "yield return null" (I mean inside a coroutine) to wait until the next frame, this is a basic technique (TBC, you often have to "actually" do this, not just when dealing with some mystery problem)

Answer (score 2):

I see your answer, good that it is fixed but it is not the best solution.

Prior to Unity3D version 5.3.1p3 this engine had problems with updating canvases, and sometimes the UI content was disapearing. You didnt tell version you use, but I am almost sure in this case it would help calling

```
Canvas.ForceUpdateCanvases ();
```

In your code it should look like that:

```
 if(hit.collider.tag == "fruit")
                {           
                    score++;
                    //showcounttext();
                    count.text =  score.ToString ();
                    print(count.text);
                    Destroy(hit.collider.gameObject,1);
                    Destroy(bullet_new,1);

                    Canvas.ForceUpdateCanvases ();
                }
```

Try this, or upgrade Unity3D.

Comment: That is interesting, however I don't notice anything about it in the [release notes](https://unity3d.com/unity/qa/patch-releases).  This is the only UI-related issue: (741751) - UI: Removed remaining uses of multiple display system.

Comment: Sorry I wasnt precise enough. By saying prior to 5.3.1p3 I meant all version and patches at least to version 5.2. I had similar problem in version 5.2 like in the question so this is my quess.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work and yes you are right my unity version is 5.0.0f4

Comment: Hi Jerry, I really think this is not the problem. I'm guessing Melissa has made some annoying little mistake ....

Comment: I see, al least tried to help. But if the upgrading Unity3D to 5.3.1p3 wont help too, must be this mistake mentioned by you.